# Is there some time between earlier version of a resource is removed, and the new one being created in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Say I want to create a SQS, and I decide to do that via CDK. Now let's say I have deployed this CDK one time, and the SQS is created.

This SQS is receiving active traffic now.

Now, I have made some change in the CDK package, and I want to deploy it again. This would mean, I think, that the previous SQS is removed, and the new is created.

Would the time between these : Removal of previous resource, and creation of the new one, cause any issues?

Should I be worried about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the CloudFormation documentation on the specific resource you're interested in. The documentation specifies what happens when you update each attribute - some updates require no interruption - the update will be seamless. Some require "some interruption" - there will be a brief interruption in the normal functioning. Some require replacement - that is, a new resource needs to be created.

CloudFormation handles replacement in a robust way - first, a new resource is created, then all the resources that depend on it are updated, then the old one is deleted. So there is no time between the removal and creation of the new one, because the new one is created before the old one is removed.